# Definition of antenna efficiency

Tags: antenna, efficiency

I have two definitions for antenna efficiency:

\$ \varepsilon = \dfrac{P_{rad}}{P_{in}}\$

and

\$ \varepsilon = \dfrac{R_{rad}}{R_{rad} + R_{ohm}}\$

Coming from physics, I was wondering if there is always a clear distinction between the active power P, reactive power Q, and complex power \$S = P + jQ\$, or if P is interchangeably used for active and complex power.

My problem is this: if P in the first equation is the active power, then it doesn't account for *all* the power in the antenna. If P in the first equation is actually the complex power S, then the two definitions are not equivalent.

Comment: What is Rohm? I take it that Rrad is the conventional resistance of free space i.e. 377 ohms? In EE when we talk about power (with no other suffix) we mean watts BTW.

Comment: \$R_{rad}\$ is the radiation resistance of the antenna. It varies with the antenna design and frequency. \$R_{ohm}\$ is the heat dissipation resistance of the antenna, it varies with the antenna design and can also be affected by frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The first is a more general definition, the basic statement of what efficiency means.

The second can be derived, if you model the antenna as a radiation resistance Rrad, in series with an Ohmic loss resistance, Rohm.

Reactive power is not considered in these equations. Why should it be, over a full wave it contributes no net power flow.

So I think the mistake in your argument is asking why P doesn't include the reactive power in the antenna. It doesn't need to; only the power *transferred to* the antenna should be considered.

(and for any alternating current, P means of course |P| integrated over a cycle, not instantaneous power. Otherwise you'll quickly get tangled in reactive power questions)

Comment: True. But then I have another question: if you design an antenna and you measure the S-parameters, it will tell you the reflection coefficient of the total power S (I think). So, then, for further antenna analysis, do you need to be careful and include the _power factor_ \$ \phi = \frac{P}{|S|} \$?

Answer (score 0):

Reactive power is just an evil needed to set the electric/magnetic field.P is the real thing.And why would P and S be used interchangeably when they are clearly different things?Both the formulas are correct.Prad is that portion of Pin that is radiated.Pin includes not only radiated power but also the power lost in the antenna structure.In antenna models,all of them are modeled in series (same current).                              Pin=I^2(Rrad+Rohm)and Prad=I^2(Rrad).You can see the first formula reduces to second.

Comment: Yes, but then, as I commented on tomnexus' answer, does the power factor come in play when you characterize an antenna using S-parameters? S-parameters giving the reflected apparent power?

Comment: Power factor relates Voltage to current and S parameters relate voltage to voltage.Why would power factor be involved then?

Comment: I guess that it could entirely be avoided since i indeed just found out that you can say either: 

\$S_t = S_i(1-|S_{11}|^2)\$, 

\$P_t = P_i(1-|S_{11}|^2)\$, or 

\$Q_t = Q_i(1-|S_{11}|^2)\$. 

But I guess that I'm curious as to how generators work, do they give a total power that gets distributed between real and imaginary, or if I have a 1w generator, will it always send out 1w of active power?

Comment: Generators don't work like that.There is nothing as a "1kW" generator,1kVA may be.They provide you both real and reactive power (some generators may require reactive power).They take both mechanical work + field excitation to work.The field excitation provides for the air gap magnetic field and rest of it is supplied as reactive power to the load.The generator power factor is decided solely by load.So you will have different active powers for different loads (the reason why generators are not rated in kW),apparent power would be the same though.That is why generators are rated in kVA